# is there any way to read and copy a javacard .cap file?

Tags: javacard

Is there any way to read a .cap file from a java card? 
or Is there any way to copy a .cap file from a Java card to another java card?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No its not possible and it is pretty obvious if you think about it.
The aim and definition for a smartcard/javacard is its high security to store data and its non-cloneability. so there is clearly no way thats works.
 I advise you to read the JavaCard Book from Zhiqun Chen. Although its from 2000 all the concept is still running and except for some new api calls there didnt change a lot

Comment: thank you paul. but for the aim of non-cloneability and high security, they can put a password (a key) for reading or copying the cap file. btw thank you. :) I understood that it is not possible based on your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible at all to do either.

Comment: If possible you should name any sources your answer is based on.